# Face Expression Change

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I have seen numerous examples and sample code for detecting emotions from a human face. I am in desperate need of some algorithm to change expressions. I am a new OpenCV learner. I am also confused if this image manipulation can be done using opencv ? Can functions such as warpaffine() be used for this ? If shall be grateful if someone can guide me in steps how to perform this eg. input a neutral face emotion and convert it to smile ?

Comment: I have been able to identify and mark ROI for features like eyes, nose and mouth. After that i m stuck.

Comment: You've run an OpenCV sample, and done nothing by yourself after that. Go google yourself for some research on topic, try to implement their approaches, write code, then come back to ask for some specific help. Btw, your project is a little too ambitious, especially for someone with low experience with OpenCV

Comment: Where did you find "examples and sample code for detecting emotions from a human face"? Please point me to at least one. Thank you.

Comment: if you have find the solution then please let us know,i am also stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Try using [FaceAPI](http://www.seeingmachines.com/product/faceapi/), it is free to use for non-commercial purposes and works brilliantly. It is well documented and easy to use.

Comment: is there any suggestion for Android then please let me know

Comment: I have worked with EmguCV, but for that you would have to purchase Xamarin's Android .NET SDK,I haven't worked BoofCV but I think is great and is open sourced and I think it supports android. Do check them out.